# SwipeRefreshLayout stops working / RecyclerView inconsistently triggers SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, swiperefreshlayout

I'm seeing an issue with RecyclerView inconsistently activating SwipeRefreshLayout on a Nexus 6P API 25 7.1.1 simulator. 
We are on the very latest versions of the support libraries:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

I have a RecyclerView with a dataset that gets prepended to when the pull to refresh occurs (adding items to the top), it's declared in my layout like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I'm able to trigger the gesture about 2-3 times, adding items to the RecyclerView but then it no longer allows me to trigger the pull-refresh. We never call SwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false). It appears the RecyclerView is internally responding true to canScrollVertically(-1) even though we're at the top of the list of items.

The only interesting thing about our handling is we override the RecyclerView's layout manager to let us scroll-to-bottom:

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
llm.setStackFromEnd(true); // Start with most recent messages (enables scroll-to-bottom)
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `View`, the code that computes `canScrollVertically(-1)` depends on the results of `computeVerticalScrollOffset`, `computeVerticalScrollRange` and `computeVerticalScrollExtent`.

The `RecyclerView` relies upon the `LinearLayoutManager` to do these computations. This forwards to `ScrollbarHelper` that does some approximations if `smoothScrollbarEnabled` is `true` (the default) in order to show a fancy scrollbar.

If the items in your `RecyclerView` are of varying sizes, these approximations will be totally wrong.

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
llm.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

Solved our problem and got the `SwipeRefreshLayout` to trigger reliably every time we got to the top of the list.